# What is "case true or true or true when [...]" syntax in switch-statements?

Tags: c#, syntax, switch-statement, intellisense, rider

I have the following code snippet in my project (I simplified it as much as possible):

```
private void someFunc(bool a, bool b, bool c, int x, int y) {
if ((a || b || c) && x != 1)
{
    // do something
} else if ((a || b || c) && y < 0)
{
    // do else
}
}
```

and IntelliJ Rider IDE offers me to *convert to switch statement*, which then gives me this:

```
private void someFunc(bool a, bool b, bool c, int x, int y) {
switch (a)
{
    case true or true or true when x != 1:
        // do something
        break;
    case true or true or true when y < 0:
        // do else
        break;
}
}
```

What kind of switch syntax is this? What is `true or true or true when` supposed to mean, it seems super redundant? And most importantly, where did `b` and `c` go??

I didn't expect this type of reformatting, and I think it must be a fairly new language feature?
I've checked the C# language documentation but didn't find an explanation for a case like this...

Comment: Well, it could have done better, but it _is_ basically just expanding your constant values in line.

Comment: Then try starting from `static void M(bool a, bool b, bool c, int x) { if ( ... ) ... }` instead.

Comment: `or` is just the pattern matching for `||`

Comment: I think it's _attempting_ to do this: [case guards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#case-guards)

Comment: The values being constant is not the reason it's refactored like this. When I define a, b, c and x as function parameters it proposes the same refactor.
So is it just plain wrong from the IDE's side?:0

Comment: It's clearly a bug in Rider. You should report it to JetBrains.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed new code does not seem to make sense.

---

Not in original answer:

The proposed refactoring is not correct. Namely, suppose you start with:

```cs
static void M(bool a, bool b, bool c, int x)
{
    if ((a || b || c) && x != 1)
    {
        // do something
    } else if ((a || b || c) && x < 0)
    {
        // do else
    }
}
```

then (using your values) `M(false, false, true, 0)` would go into the `// do something` block, whereas with:

```cs
static void M(bool a, bool b, bool c, int x)
{
    switch (a)
    {
        case true or true or true when x != 1:
            // do something
            break;
        case true or true or true when x < 0:
            // do else
            break;
    }
}
```

the call `M(false, false, true, 0)` would not enter that block.

I am not addressing the question whether "IntelliJ Rider IDE" actually suggests this change, in the way you say it does.

A better refactoring of your code seems to be:

```cs
static void M(bool a, bool b, bool c, int x)
{
    if ((a || b || c) && x != 1)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

where I have removed the `// do else` part entirely since it could never occur. This is because any number less than `0` would also be unequal to `1`.

So as hinted in some comments, your original code probably was not as you intended. However, that is still no excuse for the IDE to suggest a bad refactoring (and again, I am not verifying your claim that it really suggests this).

Comment: @stuartd The question is like "This cannot be a good refactoring, `true or true` is redundant, and the dependence on `b` and `c` was forgotten?". Then the answer should be: "You are correct".

Comment: Well, it probably means that the code wasn't so great to begin with... it's a question of how far you want to take the refactoring.

Comment: @stuartd Now I expanded it into a _long_ answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

due to  switch expressions introduced in C# 7, it could be rewirtten as follows

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        bool a = false, b = true, c = false;
        int x = -5;

        bool d = false;



        string result = (a, b, c) switch
        {
            { } when (a == true || b == true || c == true) && x != 1 && x > 0 => "1",
            { } when (a == true || b == true || c == true) && x < 0 => "2",
            _ => "3"
        };
```

/////////////////////// OR ////////////////////////

```
        switch ((a, b, c))
        {
            case { } when (a == true || b == true || c == true) && x != 1 && x > 0:
                // do something
                Console.WriteLine("1");
                break;

            case { } when (a == true || b == true || c == true) && x < 0:
                // do something
                Console.WriteLine("2");
                break;

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but not what I wanted to know

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).